# Доброго вечора або Добрий вечір?

Tags: граматика

Я кожного дня слухаю від людей **'добрий вечір'** та **'доброго вечора'**". Підскажіть, будь ласка, який із цих двох варіантів є найбільш граматично правильний?

Comment: Маємо подібне запитання: [«Cases for Ukrainian salutations: Доброго ранку vs Добрий ранок; Добрий день vs Доброго дня; Добрий вечір vs Доброго вечора?»](/q/395) — але воно англійською.

Answer (score 8):

В [експрес-уроці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9tXngTv8ds&vl=uk) української мови Олександр Авраменко каже, що правильним варіантом є "Добрий вечір", причина - мовна традиція:

> Добрий вечір тобі, пане господарю

А не "доброго вечора тобі".

Дивимося на сайті [Цікава мова](http://cikavamova.blogspot.com/2017/03/blog-post.html):

> По-перше, українці віками віталися "Добрий день!" і "Добрий вечір!".
>   Саме форми в називному відмінку наявні і в народній творчості, і у
>   творах письменників. Натомість форми "Доброго дня!" і "Доброго
>   вечора!" практично відсутні і там, і там.
>
> По-друге, вітальні формули самі в собі є побажаннями. Це усталені
>   конструкції, слова ввічливості. У різних піснях ми чуємо "Добрий день
>   вам, люди добрі!", "Щедрий вечір, добрий вечір добрим людям на
>   здоров'я!", "Добрий вечір тобі, пане господарю!" і так далі.
>
> По-третє, для того, щоб побажати щось людині, кажуть: "Гарного дня
>   (вам)!", "Вдалого дня (вам)!". Такі побажання переважно говорять на
>   прощання, а не при зустрічі.

Є схожа [стаття](https://uamodna.com/articles/vitaymosj-po-ukrayinsjkomu/) і на сайті Українська мова, де теж пише, що правильно казати "добрий вечір".

Хоча, сайт [Як правильно](https://kak-pravilno.net/dobrogo-vechora-chi-dobriy-vechir-yak-pravilno/) зазначає, що можливі обидва варіанти і навіть пише, що варіант "доброго вечора" стає поширенішим. І все ж, я б радив вам використовувати варіант "добрий вечір", бо навіть у [Російсько-українському словнику](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%96%D1%80&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) можна знайти його, а от "доброго вечора" там немає.

Answer (score -3):

Коли звертають до декількох людей- доброго вечора
Коли звертаються до однієї людини-добрий вечір

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Цікава версія. Що саме Ви можете сказати на її підтримку? Як обґрунтувати?