# Чи правильно казати "Доброго вечорУ"?

Tags: вживання-слів, правопис, словосполучення, родовий-відмінок

Почула вперше, що зробили зауваження на письмове привітання *"Доброго вечора"*, що це не правильно, а правильно вітатись — *"Доброго вечору"*.

Чи дійсно так?

Comment: Добрий вечір!) Це питання вже обговорювалося на сайті. Знайти його ви можете ось тут: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5206/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be-%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%96%d1%80

Comment: Дякую за відповідь) Це я бачила. Хочу почути вашу думку саме про словосполучення "доброго вечору", тому що почула таке вперше)

Comment: Було б добре взнати думку того, хто вам зауважив/а. Бо звичаьево родовиь відмінок [лиш з **а**](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=вечір). Однак [пошук вказуье](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&safe=off&q="доброго+вечору"), шчо _~ вечору_ вживаниь. Можу лише _припустити_ шчо сье ьакиьсь [новопольонізм](//sjp.pwn.pl/poradnia/haslo/;13281.html). За лоґікоьу ьак абстракне підходить, але не гармоніьуье з иншими безваріьативними _~ днь**а**_, але з _~ ранк**у**_. Отже коротко — **неправильно**, але цьікава причина [ьак похоџеньа і лоґіки] ьавишча.

Comment: @stegetsj, зі «з ранку» якраз гармонує, по-моєму; а от зі «з дня» справді ні.

Answer (score 6):

## Проти форми «доброго вечору»

- Правильною формою родового відмінка слова *[вечір](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7752&page=284)* вважається «вечора» (а не «вечору»); а після прикметника в родовому відмінку («доброго») може йти лише родовий відмінок іменника (а не давальний).
- Ніде в класичній літературі чи словниках немає форми «доброго вечору» (а «добрий вечір» і «доброго вечора» трапляються неодноразово).

Можна сперечатися про те, **[як краще — «добрий вечір» чи «доброго вечора»](/q/5206)** (деякі мовознавці стверджують, що лише перший варіант традиційний, інші ж вважають обидва варіанти прийнятними), але саме варіант **«доброго вечору» зараз вважається поза нормою**.

## На захист форми «доброго вечору»

З іншого боку, мова не стоїть на місці. І варіант «доброго вечору» таки вживається в розмовній мові й навіть поодиноко в сучасних книжках:

- — Доброго вечору! Мене звати Ліля і я буду вашою офіціанткою, — повторюю я завчений текст. — Чого бажаєте? //Юлія Шеко, «Поміж грядками», 2018.
- Доброго вечору. Маю термінову роботу курьером для мотоциклістів на завтра (06 вересня) у Києві. Потрібно 2-3 людини на цілий день. Якщо комусь… //З Фейсбуку, 2018.
- Доброго вечору! Опублікуйте, будь ласка. Загублено чорний клатч-гаманець з документами сьогодні ввечері в районі сільпо-автовокзалу //З Фейсбуку, 2018.
- Доброго вечору! Допоможіть, будь ласка, розібратися з терміном відпустки. Я працюю в даній школі з 1 вересня 2016 року. З 2 червня… //З підсайту констультацій на jobs.ua, 2017.
- І вам доброго вечору :) таке приємне побажання! дякую, ви трішки розрадили мене) ось сиджу біля вікна, дивлюсь на вогні нічного міста… //З ask.fm, 2015.
- І т.д., причому до 2009 року лише 3 трапляння, а з 2010 — понад кілька десятків.

Мабуть, це можна пояснити тим, що «вечору» в деяких діалектах чи в розмовній мові загалом почало сприйматися як форма родового відмінку слова *вечір* (адже в українській мові деякі іменники 2-ї відміни мають родовий відмінок однини на *-а*, деякі на *-у*, а деякі хитаються залежно від значення чи діалекта). З точки зору норм літературної мови це **неправильно** (формою родового відмінка для *вечір* має бути лише «вечора», незалежно від значення). Але я не став би ганити тих, хто каже «доброго вечору» — можливо, якщо не перешкоджати природному розвитку мови, це колись стане новою нормою.

## Висновок

З точки зору сучасних **норм літературної української мови правильно лише «добрий вечір» і «доброго вечора»** (причому мовознавці сперечаються, чи ці варіанти повністю рівноцінні, чи варто надавати перевагу першому як традиційнішому). Але вживання варіанта **«доброго вечору»** в розмовній мові, здається (судячи з мережі), **«набирає оберти»**. Хоча мені важко сказати, чи це стосується лише певного регіону, чи всієї України.

Answer (score 4):

*Вечір* — це іменник **чоловічого роду II відміни**.

Стаття на Вікіпедії [Родовий відмінок однини іменників чоловічого роду другої відміни](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8) містить пояснення на цю тему (із посиланнями на кілька поважних джерел), що іменник дістає закінчення `-а/-я` або `-у/-ю` **в залежності від свого лексичного значення**.

На мою думку, найбільше підходять наступні категорії:

- *11.* Збірні поняття […] ;
- *14.* Переважна більшість слів зі значенням місця, простору тощо […]
  *(Зауваження: напевно, і часу також)*;
- *15.* Явища природи;

Усі вищезазначені категорії мають `-у/-ю` в родовому відмінку: *«доброго **вечору**»*.

З іншого боку, в усталеній практиці упевнено переважає *«доброго **вечора**»*  (див. сусідню відповідь з кількісними оцінками).

Також, варто поглянути на подібні слова *«доброго ранк**у**»* та *«доброго дн**я**»* — вони обидва належать до II відміни, але у родовому відмінку отримують різні закінчення.

---

**Висновок:** Якщо суто-формально послуговуватися правилами, то варіант ***«вечору»*** має право на існування. Але, враховуючи низьку популярність цього варіанту і можливість беззмістовних суперечок зі співрозмовниками на тему граматики, я б використовував ***вечора***.

---

Див. також:

- [Родовий відмінок слова "граф" (математичний термін): графА чи графУ?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/)
- [Як правильно: "трамвая" чи "трамваю"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/427/)
- [Як правильно - "елемента" чи "елементу"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/)

Comment: Я б краще посилався на «Правопис» чи конкретну книжку (бо Вікіпедія в тій статті, на жаль, не зазначає джерела попунктово).
Але загалом аргумент, по-моєму, доречний — по-моєму, _вечір_ може сприйматися як «явище природи» (як і _ранок_), у той час як для _день_, по-моєму, переважає значення «міра часу» (а не «явище природи»).